# keep leading zeros and decimals when exporting XML file from Excel

Tags: excel, xml, leading-zero

I have imported an XML file into Excel without any schema/map. Excel has created a map based on the data. I have remapped the items and formatted the cells as they should appear.

Leading zeros example:

[image]

I use this formatting because if I use Text, it does not work when I import new date from another XML file. The leading zeros are stripped down.

Decimals example:

[image]

Same reason for the formatting as above.

The problem:
When I export the data to an XML file all this formatting is stripped down.
Example:
[image]

Is there a way to retain that formatting when exporting from Excel? I checked other topics connected with this issue but there is no definitive answer or solution.

Comment: I'll admit I don't have experience with importing/exporting from and to xml but this must be because the underlying value is still the same. All the formatting does is change how excel displays the value, but the value itself remains without the leading zeroes. Is it possible for you to create a new column in the table, format it with the TEXT function like so: =TEXT([@doc_n],"0000000000") and then use that column for export instead?

Comment: You are exactly right. I did not think about that. The formatting is correct, but the value is still without leading zero or decimals.
https://pasteboard.co/fjRToG1WIRFc.png

So the problem actually comes from the import. The Excel strips down the leading zeros and decimals during the import, even though I have formatted the cells correctly. The initial XML file that I import has this data.

Comment: I will try the method with the text function and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by @andrewb actually worked.

You just need to import the XML into excel and re-map the XML schema to different cells where you can use the TEXT function:

```
=TEXT([@any_cell],"0000000000")
```

To refer to the cell with the data and format it the way you want. It does keep leading zeros and decimals when you export it back to XML format.

I actually created 2 schema maps - one for importing the data and one for exporting the data with formatting. Excel asks when you save which map to use.